# How can I create a dead weakref in python?

Tags: python, weak-references

Is there a better way of doing this than:

```
def create_expired_weakref():
    class Tmp: pass
    ref = weakref.ref(Tmp())
    assert ref() is None
    return ref
```

Context: I want a default state for my weakref, so that my class can do:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._ref = create_expired_weakref()

def get_thing(self):
    r = self._ref()  # I need an empty weakref for this to work the first time
    if r is None:
        r = SomethingExpensive()
        self._ref = weakref.ref(r)
    return r
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `weakref.ref` object? If you don't care about the type, you could use `lambda: None` as the default value.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Nice idea - that works for my use-case, but I'm still curious if there's a way to produce a real weakref (which would make mypy happy, for instance)

Comment: Or use `type(None)` if you don't like lambda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use duck typing here.  If all you care about is that it behaves like a dead weakref with respect to the `self._ref()` call, then you can do

```
self._ref = lambda : None
```

This is what I ended up using when I had a similar desire to have a property that would return a cached value if it was available, but None otherwise.  I initialized it with this lambda function.  Then the property was

```
@property
def ref(self):
    return self._ref()
```

Update: Credit to @Aran-Fey, who I see posted this idea as a comment to the question, rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use you a `weakref.finalize` for great good:

```
import weakref

def create_expired_weakref(type_=type("", (object,), {'__slots__':
                                      ('__weakref__',)})):
    obj = type_()
    ref = weakref.ref(obj)
    collected = False

    def on_collect():
        nonlocal collected
        collected = True
    final = weakref.finalize(obj, on_collect)
    del obj

    while not collected:
        pass
    return ref
```

This might block the thread for a while if you're debugging, and might even deadlock in some obscure situations, but it's guaranteed to return an expired weakref.